# Catching selected portion of the string in python

Tags: python

I have a variable Field in which a string is store like this:

```
Field= "In Field 'fieldname':(Value1) from (DC) to (deleted)"
```

or it can also be:

```
 Field= "In Field 'fieldname':(Value1) has changed from (DC) to (1)"
```

From this string stored in variable Field, I want to catch the values (DC) and (deleted) or (DC) to (1) in two different variables like:

```
OldValue=DC
NewValue=deleted

OldValue=DC
NewValue=1
```

I am handling this variables in Python like this:

```
 OldValue,NewValue=re.findall(r'\((\d+)\)',Field)
```

But this catches only digits not string? Can anyone help

Comment: Did you consider using an existing serialization format rather than making up your own?

Comment: Using XML, JSON, YAML, ... or some other pre-existing format makes this sort of thing trivial because the formats are well defined and there are tons of existing libraries already for reading & writing such formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\d` in a regular expression matches digits only. In order to match letters (`\w`) and digits (`\d`), the best solution is a character class of both (`[\d\w]`).

Note: this will also catch the `(Value1)` in your string. You'll need some code to filter it out; or, just modify the tuple:

```
ValueName, OldValue, NewValue = tuple(re.findall(r'\(([\d\w]+?)\)', Field))
```

Notes:

1. The `+?` modifier matches the least possible nonzero number of `[\d\w]`s (unlike `+`, which matches the highest possible number).
2. The `tuple()` is necessary to convert the list returned by `re.findall` into a tuple that the left side can make sense of.

Comment: @hulk007 On my Python (2.7.3) `re.findall` returns a list. If it's the same on your Python I'll edit that in.

Comment: for me its python 2.4.3, it gives me the values but with errroe I written above

Comment: If `re.findall` is only returning 2 matches, there's a problem with the regex or the data. My testing on the data in the question shows my regex works fine, and I can't find any substantial differences between 2.4.3 and 2.7.3 in terms of regexes, so some of your data must be more complicated than in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your existing `re` to be:

```
>>> re.search(r'from \((.*?)\) to \((.*?)\)$', Field).groups()
('DC', 'deleted')
```

Comment: Attribute Error:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'